# Is there a way to comment on a track using Soundcloud Python?

Tags: python-2.7, soundcloud

The Soundcloud API reference is a little confusing to me. I've learned how to do a lot of things with it, but I can't figure out if I can comment on a song.

If I understand the reference correctly, when something has the options GET,PUT,DELETE next to it, that means you can get it, post it, and delete it.

But that's a wild educated guess and I could be really misinterpreting this.

I've tried

```
import soundcloud

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=id,
                       client_secret=secret,
                       username=email,
                       password=password)

client.put('/tracks/'+str(trackID)+'/comments/', body="Reposted")
```

but that didn't work. If there is no way of doing this, what does the PUT here mean? Below is taken from the [API reference](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#comments).

```
GET, PUT, DELETE    /tracks/{id}/comments/{comment-id}  a comment for the track
```

Comment: Can you include your full code please?

Also I can't help but wonder why you'd need a script for SoundCloud commenting, but that's not my business, is it? :P

Comment: Updated to include the rest of the code, not sure how that will help though!

Also, I would just like to comment "reposted @ url" when I repost something, to raise awareness to my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. The docs suggest calling `post` instead of `put`.
2. Your body needs to be a dictionary with the key `body` and optionally a `timestamp`.

```
client.post('/tracks/%d/comments' % track.id, comment={
    'body': 'This is a timed comment'
})
```

Comment: Ahh Thank you! I was afraid there wouldn't be a way.

And also, where does it suggest using post instead of put? I'm just trying to get a better handle on the reference. I honestly don't know where it says to use dictionary format either? How do I know what uses that format and what doesn't??

Comment: HTTP API Guide -> Comments -> Python https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#comments